# RHEL SELinux context differs between matchpathcon and restorecon

Tags: rhel6, selinux

I am using RHEL 6.3 and I experiment a strange behavior with *matchpathcon* and *restorecon* SELinux commands. For a specific file, I have defined a context with *semanage fcontext*. Then, *matchpathcon* tells me that the file should have the context I defined but *restorecon* make the file have an other context. I can't understand the behavior and I think there is something I do wrong.

Here is an example to reproduce this behavior (I am a root user):

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)

$ sestatus 
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

I would create a specific init.d script to launch an HTTPD daemon.

```
$ touch /etc/init.d/my-httpd
$ ls -Z /etc/init.d/my-httpd 
-rw-------. root root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   /etc/init.d/my-httpd
```

So, I create the context for this file and I check it has been saved.

```
$ semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_initrc_exec_t /etc/init.d/my-httpd
$ semanage fcontext -C -l
contexte fichier SELinux                           type               Contexte

/etc/init.d/my-httpd                               all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_initrc_exec_t:s0

matchpathcon -V /etc/init.d/my-httpd 
/etc/init.d/my-httpd has context unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0, should be system_u:object_r:httpd_initrc_exec_t:s0
```

Then, I try to restore the context to what *matchpathcon* told me.

```
restorecon -v /etc/init.d/my-httpd 
restorecon reset /etc/rc.d/init.d/my-httpd context unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:initrc_exec_t:s0

$ ls -Z /etc/init.d/my-httpd 
-rw-------. root root unconfined_u:object_r:initrc_exec_t:s0 /etc/init.d/my-httpd
```

At this point, I get that the context have not been defined as I would. I try to check again with *matchpathcon*, maybe httpd_initrc_exec_t is an alias of initrc_exec_t.

```
matchpathcon -V /etc/init.d/my-httpd 
/etc/init.d/my-httpd has context unconfined_u:object_r:initrc_exec_t:s0, should be system_u:object_r:httpd_initrc_exec_t:s0

$ restorecon -v -F /etc/init.d/my-httpd 
restorecon reset /etc/rc.d/init.d/my-httpd context unconfined_u:object_r:initrc_exec_t:s0->system_u:object_r:initrc_exec_t:s0

$ matchpathcon -V /etc/init.d/my-httpd 
/etc/init.d/my-httpd has context system_u:object_r:initrc_exec_t:s0, should be system_u:object_r:httpd_initrc_exec_t:s0
```

Then, I try to fix manually the context with *chcon*, but that is not the way I want to do this. It is just to check the previous alias theory.

```
$ chcon -t httpd_initrc_exec_t /etc/init.d/my-httpd 
$ ls -Z /etc/init.d/my-httpd 
-rw-------. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_initrc_exec_t:s0 /etc/init.d/my-httpd
$ matchpathcon -V /etc/init.d/my-httpd 
/etc/init.d/my-httpd verified.

$ restorecon -v /etc/init.d/my-httpd 
restorecon reset /etc/rc.d/init.d/my-httpd context system_u:object_r:httpd_initrc_exec_t:s0->system_u:object_r:initrc_exec_t:s0
```

These contexts do not seem to be aliases, but there is still a strange behavior with *restorecon* command, and I have planned to use its functionality.

Is there an other way to define this SELinux context or maybe have I done something wrong ?

Comment: This might be a bug. You need to (1) update your system; (2) contact Red Hat support and open a case.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I see the same thing on a CentOS 6.5 system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Red Hat support told me the right way to operate.
The context shall be set for */etc/rc.d/init.d/my-httpd* and not for */etc/init.d/my-httpd*.

```
$ semanage fcontext -d -t httpd_initrc_exec_t /etc/init.d/my-httpd
$ semanage fcontext -C -l
$ semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_initrc_exec_t /etc/rc.d/init.d/my-httpd
$ semanage fcontext -C -l
SELinux fcontext                                   type               Context

/etc/rc.d/init.d/my-httpd                          all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_initrc_exec_t:s0
```

Once the correct context rule set, *restorecon* works on */etc/init.d/my-httpd* file.

```
ls -Z /etc/rc.d/init.d/my-httpd /etc/init.d/my-httpd
-rw-------. root root system_u:object_r:initrc_exec_t:s0 /etc/init.d/my-httpd
-rw-------. root root system_u:object_r:initrc_exec_t:s0 /etc/rc.d/init.d/my-httpd
$ restorecon /etc/init.d/my-httpd
$ ls -Z /etc/rc.d/init.d/my-httpd /etc/init.d/my-httpd
-rw-------. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_initrc_exec_t:s0 /etc/init.d/my-httpd
-rw-------. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_initrc_exec_t:s0 /etc/rc.d/init.d/my-httpd
```

Comment: Is this because /etc/init.d/ is a link ?

Comment: Yes, "/etc/init.d" and "/etc/rc.d/init.d" have the same inode. But restorecon did not get the right context because the original file is under the "/etc/rc.d/init.d" directory, I think.